# error while trying to play .mp4 file

Tags: gstreamer, mp4

after agree to download and install extra multimedia plugins,

it says package dependency can not be resolved, with below error:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:i386: 
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
                                Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4) but 1.12.3+git20120608.f228769d-0ubuntu0ricotz~quantal0 is to be installed
                                Depends: libcdaudio1 (>= 0.99.12p2) but 0.99.12p2-12 is to be installed
                                Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but 7.27.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libdvdnav4 (>= 4.2.0+20120524) but 4.2.0+20120524-2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libfaad2 (>= 2.7) but 2.7-8 is to be installed
                                Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but 2.34.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13) but 1.0.13-4 is to be installed
                                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 (= 0.10.23-7ubuntu1) but 0.10.23-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.36) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.36) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but 2:0.1~r459-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libopenal1 (>= 1:1.13) but 1:1.14-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but 1.2.49-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.36.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: librtmp0 (>= 2.3) but 2.4+20111222.git4e06e21-1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.9) but 1.0.11-2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libsndfile1 (>= 1.0.20) but 1.0.25-5 is to be installed
                                Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but 1.0.1c-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but 1.1.0-1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2) but 2:1.3.2-9 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem.

I solved it by going to the Ubuntu Software Center and installing the following packages:

```
GStreamer extra plugins
GStreamer ffmpeg video plugin
GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack,qucktime,musepack
```

After installing all these packages I could play video without problems.

As far as I understand the system should be able to install the dependent packages by itself but there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad0.10/+bug/914696)